# MongoDb sum list with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55fbffbdebdbc43337b08946"), "date" : 1442578343617, 
    "body" : { "entries" : [ 
        { "url" : "google.com/randomString", "time" : 143.832}, 
        { "url" : "youtube.com/randomString", "time" : 170.128}, 
        { "url" : "google.com/randomString", "time" : 125.428} 
    ] } }
```

And I want to sum the time that takes to load the google.com webpages.

What I am trying to do is:

```
    db.har.aggregate([
        {$match: {date: 1442578343617, "body.entries.url": /google/}},
        { $unwind : "$body.log.entries"}, 
        { $group : {"_id" : 123,"total" : {$sum:"$body.entries.time"}}}
    ])
```

But the result I get is the total sum: `{ "_id" : 123, "total" : 439.388 }`

How do I filter by body.entries.url?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: You forgot to put another **`$match`** pipeline step after the **`$unwind`** stage that will filter your documents further down the **`$group`** pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are unwinding wrong array `body.log.entries`.

You need to first match by date timestamp to filter out documents and then use $unwind and again match `body.entries.url` like :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
    date: 1442578343617
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$body.entries"
}, {
    $match: {
    "body.entries.url": /google/
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    "_id": null, //you can use any other param here
    "total": {
        $sum: "$body.entries.time"
    }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by url before unwinding keeps all the documents that **contain** a google url. But it will also keep the other urls of a document that contains google (in this case: youtube). So when you unwind you will still have those youtube urls and never filter them.

So just:

```
db.har.aggregate([
    {$match: {date: 1442578343617},
    {$unwind : "$body.log.entries"},
    {$match: {"body.entries.url": /google/},
    {$group: {"_id" : 123,"total" : {$sum:"$body.entries.time"}}}
])
```